# I'd like to generate a SCORM compliant test or assessment from a flat-file or XML format

Tags: import, scorm

Here's the deal.  We've got a bunch of test questions that have been exported from another system ... and they aren't in a SCORM compliant format.

Even if they were, we really need to get all of this data into a real learning content authoring tool.

The incumbent tool is Articulate, and as any search of the Articulate support site shows, there's no way to actually import a test question into Articulate.

Since we've got a lot of data that we'd prefer not to re-key, my question is, what's a good course authoring tool that can generate a SCORM 2004 assessment, and has a good import from flat file function for its question data?

Googling isn't really getting me too far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SCORM is used to create SCOs (shareable content objects, aka 'lessons' or 'courses') which may optionally contain questions, but SCORM isn't a quiz/assessment framework. Because it isn't an assessment framework, there is no importer for turning an XML file into a SCORM assessment.

If you can't get Articulate to work for you, then you'll probably need to roll your own SCORM SCO and build a quiz system for it (with the ability to import your custom XML files). Ideally, each quiz question would be set up as an interaction (using cmi.interactions) in SCORM.

You may want to look at some open-source SCORM SCO building tools, such as eXe and Reload, though I'm not sure how helpful they'll be for you.

Sorry I don't know of any easier solutions.

EDIT: 
BTW there's a workaround for importing XML into in Articulate: import the XML containing the questions into Quizmaker 2, then import your Quizmaker 2 presentation into Quizmaker '09. Not the easiest, but still easier than building your own SCO. See http://www.articulate.com/forums/articulate-quizmaker/3239-securing-quizmaker-xml-file.html

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer - I haven't worked with IMS-QTI personally, I just know of it.*

You may want to take a look at [IMS-QTI](http://www.imsglobal.org/question/), and see if that format would work for you.  IMS-QTI stands for IMS Question and Test Interoperability.  There may be other formats, but IMS-QTI is the only one I'm aware of, and I'm sure there would be tools out there which support it.

That would change your search to finding a tool which supports IMS-QTI, and you may have better luck with that.  :-)

There are some general examples of what kinds of questions it supports in the [implementation guide](http://www.imsglobal.org/question/qtiv2p1pd2/imsqti_implv2p1pd2.html).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Captivate or Articulate supports question import in any easy workflow. Your honest fastest route might be to author your own SCORM package format that will import questions from XML or JSON. Then write a converter to put your CSV content into XML or JSON. There are lots of SCORM API wrappers out there to use, and you'll have more control over any issues you find with LMS vs authorware interpretations of SCORM if you just build your own player.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is now available in Claro:

http://feedback.dominknow.com/knowledgebase/articles/312552-how-do-i-import-test-questions-from-excel